# Is it possible to batch load data into neo4j console?

Tags: console, neo4j, cypher

Is there a way to make the console use the data imported into the graph database? 
I tried this address:
http://console.neo4j.org/?init=http://localhost:7474/db/data/cypher
while running the server but can't get any data to show up when I try to run basic queries (MATCH n RETURN n LIMIT 25) 
also the toggle viz doesn't produce anything.

Comment: The address of your server has to be publicly accessible.

Comment: @MichaelHunger I don't quite understand. I went here:</br> http://docs.neo4j.org/chunked/stable/security-server.html</br> and per the instructions commented out the http port line (with the localhost info) then uncommented this line:</br> org.neo4j.server.webserver.address=0.0.0.0</br> and saved, then ran the server and it still points to localhost and the console won't load correctly. I'm not sure what I'm missing?

Comment: you have to provide the external IP that a computer on the internet (i.e. the console) can use to load the data from, or you go to the github.com/neo4j-contrib/rabbithole repo and check out and run the console locally.